# How to Edit Status setting in Informatica cloud under Monitor tab

Tags: cloud, informatica, informatica-cloud

My teammate can see a resume option when she hovers over the status under all jobs in the Informatica cloud. I don't want to restart my job but unfortunately, I cannot see that option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nSC0.png)

Comment: The "resume" option will be available if the workflow has been suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit the status in IICS to my knowledge. You can resume or end the task. You should be able to resume your job - you may not have the correct admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

We can resume the failed steps. Informatica changed the way we could do this. Earlier under my jobs under status, we had an option to resume from failed step. Now we need to click on the instance name and on the top right we can see the option after the job status is under suspended state.